# What did Lily really say?

Tags: modern-family

In Modern Family Season 3 Episode 13, "Little Bo Bleep", Lily starts saying a certain swear word beginning with F. I've read that this has caused controversy but I'm pretty sure that it was only because they were showing a child swearing. Of course in the show the word was bleeped out so I'm also pretty sure the actress never actually says that word.

Do we know what she actually said?

Comment: Uh, any infamous swear words starting with F that come to mind? ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Well it's only stated it begins with F, the rest is left to your imagination...

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - [Ralphie knows what you're talking about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJMZDBEL8Tg) :D

Comment: [Fuu-cryingoutloud](https://youtu.be/wTia_bXukW4?t=33s)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found a tweet from Eric Stonestreet, the actor who plays Cameron, that states she actually says Fudge.

> Lily didn't ACTUALLY say FU*K. **She said fudge.** How bout see the episode, THEN form an opinion. For fudge sake people. Chill the fuck out.
>   <sub>[Twitter, @ericstonestreet](https://twitter.com/ericstonestreet/status/157741141985464320)</sub>